# Strange behavior with gdb printf

Tags: gdb

I have a issue with gdb `printf` in version 9.1

```
echo -e '#include<stdio.h> \n int main(){ \n printf("Hello"); \n }' > test.c

gcc -g test.c -o test

echo 'break test.c:4' > test.gdb
echo 'run' >> test.gdb
echo 'set $aux = (char*)malloc(256)' >> test.gdb
echo 'set $e = strcpy($aux, "abc")' >> test.gdb
echo 'printf "%s", $aux' >> test.gdb

gdb --batch --command=test.gdb test
```

Output with gdb 9.1:

```
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1167: file test.c, line 4.

Breakpoint 1, main () at test.c:4
4    }
�e���
```

Expected output (same as gdb v8):

```
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1167: file test.c, line 4.

Breakpoint 1, main () at test.c:4
4    }
abc
```

I've checked `charset`, but it seems ok.
Any idea about that?

Comment: This is [Bug 25650 - GDB can't 'printf' a convenience variable holding an inferior address](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25650), fixed in gdb 9.2.

Comment: Thanks @MarkPlotnick
At least this question serves as a reference since some Linux distributions have their default gdb packages still at version 9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [Bug 25650 - GDB can't 'printf' a convenience variable holding an inferior address](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25650), fixed in gdb 9.2.

If you can't upgrade to gdb 9.2 but can recompile your existing distro's gdb 9.1, there is a two-line  [patch](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blobdiff;f=gdb/printcmd.c;h=0df9826888a84d230cf4166b4566207463b7d1de;hp=ed2c8d47add3ff980c403625cbdf4a86f47fc43e;hb=141e490226a99e0359393ddaca5628c68de036dc;hpb=68a0b9582924d4c39696e61f8c84289b0759ce2a).

On Ubuntu 20.04, which comes with gdb 9.1-0ubuntu1:

1. run `apt build-dep gdb` to haul in the packages needed to build gdb from source
2. run `apt install dpkg-dev` (to get `/usr/bin/dpkg-source`)
3. uncomment the `deb-src` lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list`
4. run `apt update`
5. cd to an empty directory and run `apt source gdb` . Doing this in a fresh new directory will make it easier to clean things up after the compilation.
6. cd to `gdb-9.1` and apply the [patch](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blobdiff_plain;f=gdb/printcmd.c;h=0df9826888a84d230cf4166b4566207463b7d1de;hp=ed2c8d47add3ff980c403625cbdf4a86f47fc43e;hb=141e490226a99e0359393ddaca5628c68de036dc;hpb=68a0b9582924d4c39696e61f8c84289b0759ce2a) to `gdb/printcmd.c`
7. build and install gdb. For example, to put it in `/usr/local/bin`, the default, you'd run

```
      mkdir build
      cd build
      ../configure
      make
      make install
```